# TypeScript union in enums

Tags: typescript, enums, union

I've got a problem in TypeScript that I can't seem to solve.

Here's the code

```
enum test{
    PowerAttack = 2,
    MagicAttack = 5,
    Attack = PowerAttack && MagicAttack //invalid
}

document.body.innerHTML = (test.PowerAttack == test.Attack).toString(); //check1
document.body.innerHTML += (test.MagicAttack == test.Attack).toString();//check2
```

How can I make the two checks work?

I am trying to make test.Attack be equal to test.PowerAttack AND test.MagicAttack, but I can't make it work.
Is it possible to do that with enums? Please note that I'll have many other entries in the enum, so I don't really want to mess with bitwise operators as it will get unreadable and unmaintainable pretty quickly.

If it's not possible to make it work with enums, what's the best logic to adopt? Classes and sub-classes? Types? Else?

Comment: It's not possible to make it with equality - if Attack is equal to PowerAttack and Attack is equal to MagicAttack, then PowerAttack must be equal to MagicAttack.

Comment: *I am trying to make test.Attack be equal to test.PowerAttack AND test.MagicAttack* How can something be equal to two different things at the same time? By "equal", do you mean "matches" in a bitwise sense? Did you mean `or` (`|`) instead of `and` (`&`) (presumably not logical and (`&&`)?

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "invalid"? The code you give compiles fine for me (although as it stands it probably doesn't do what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to use enum values as flags. The simplest way to do it is to go with single bit binary numbers. e.g.

```
enum Test {
    PowerAttack = 1 << 0,
    MagicAttack = 1 << 1,
    Attack = PowerAttack | MagicAttack
}
```

Then you can test as:

```
var test: Test // you get this from somewhere
if (test & Test.Attack) {
    console.log('has attack');
}
```

## More

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html#enums-as-flags

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. I did not see the operator difference inside the if statement. Though, is there a standard way to set a value to the next enum members?
For example, NotAnAttack in the code below returns true for (Action.NotAnAttack & Action.Attack), but doesn't if I assign it 1 << 2. I read the compiled JS and it makes sense, but I just wanted to know if there was a standard/automatic way of preventing this behavior.

`enum Action {
    PowerAttack = 1 << 0,
    MagicAttack = 1 << 1,
    NotAnAttack,
    Attack = PowerAttack | MagicAttack,
}`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want

```
enum test{
    PowerAttack = 2,
    MagicAttack = 5,
    Attack = PowerAttack | MagicAttack
}
```

We define `test.Attack` as the bitwise or of the two other values, in other words 7.

Now `test.PowerAttack` and `test.MagicAttack` can be tested for "membership" in `test.Attack` by saying `test.PowerAttack & test.Attack`. If you want bit-based enums, you can't avoid using `&` to test inclusion--that's just how you have to do it.

```
document.body.innerHTML = (test.PowerAttack & test.Attack).toString(); //check1
document.body.innerHTML += (test.MagicAttack & test.Attack).toString();//check2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comment, they helped me understand the whole bitwise concept, and as I said on my other comment to @basarat 's post, I completely missed the fact that it was a `&` and not a `==` operator inside the condition statement.
Even though your example works well for this case, as soon as I add two other members in the enum, it overlaps with test.Attack's value (7).